# merging code outside of git into an existing git project

Tags: git, merge, rebase

I have an existing git project, let's call it BobCrane. This needed to completely re-work this project's extensive directory structure.

I created the needed directory structure on the filesystem, outside of any git project. I then manually copied each file from the cloned BobCrane repo into this new directory structure. So the new directories are filled with old files; there are only one or two new ones that didn't exist before.

How can I add/commit/push this new structure to the existing git repo? Is this related to "rebasing"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. init a git repository at new directory structure

```
    git init
```

2. commit all files

```
    git add -A
    git commit -m "commit message"
```

3. add your existing repository remote

```
    git remote add origin your_existing_repository@url
```

---

**Merge approach**

4. pull changes from remote

```
    git pull origin remote_branch_name
```

5. after resolving all conflicts execute

```
    git add -A
    git merge --continue
```

---

**Rebase approach**

4. Fetch changes from remote

```
    git fetch
```

5.1. Rebase onto remote branch

```
    git rebase origin/remote_branch_name
```

5.2. Resolve conflicts if any and execute

```
    git add -A
    git rebase --continue
```

---

6. push new commits into your existing repository

```
    git push -u origin remote_branch_name
```

**Rebase** is preferred way because it will produce cleaner commits history